# OpenCV: cvRandArr in C

Tags: c, opencv, random

So I have been working with openCV for a current project, and I am trying to generate some normally distributed random numbers. I am doing this entirely in C, NOT C++ (not by choice mind you), so I have run into yet another headache.

Basically, I want to know how to properly call this code segment:

```
CvMat* noise = cvCreateMat( 10, 1, CV_64FC1 );
CvRNG rng[] = { cvRNG(time(NULL)), cvRNG(time(NULL)) };
cvRandArr( rng, noise, CV_RAND_NORMAL, cvScalar(0,0,0,0), cvScalar(1,1,1,1) );
```

Where the cvScalars represent the mean and standard deviation of the distribution, from left to right, respectively. Now, in the C++ implementations I viewed online, I saw things like:

```
cvRandArr( rng, noise, CV_RAND_NORMAL, cvScalar(0), cvScalar(1) );
```

And it apparently works fine. When compiling that with GCC, I get:

```
error: too few arguments to function ‘cvScalar’
```

So, I call it like the first example. However, I can also write things like:

```
cvRandArr( rng, noise, CV_RAND_NORMAL, cvScalar(0,NAN,NAN,NAN), cvScalar(1,0,0,0) );
```

And still get what appear to be signed random numbers. So without running Q-Q plots on all the possible permutations of the above pattern (36 in the simplest case), does anyone know whether or not the extra values have any effect on the result?

Note that this:

```
cvRandArr( rng, noise, CV_RAND_NORMAL, cvScalar(0,NAN,NAN,NAN), cvScalar(0,NAN,NAN,NAN) );
```

Gives me all zeros at the output, so it 'appears' that the first argument is both necessary and sufficient to give me a random number set....but that doesn't give me a clue as to what those other arguments are actually doing, if they aren't NaNs.

Any ideas?

Comment: @TheDude, btw, try to supply a plain cvRNG(..) to your function, not an array (that part got deleted, too)

Comment: in other words, - you fed a CvRng** to a function, that expects a CvRng*. you did not see the difference between 2stars and one star, neither did your compiler.. you're still sure, that using this is a good idea ?